# Accessing Database with python or command line

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am able to access and query the database on the web interface of PhPMyAdmin using a user credentials. However, when I am trying the following command line commands:

```
mysql -h (<url of phpmyadmin>) -u (<non-root username>) -p (<database>)
```

Or this error:

> ERROR 2059 (HY000): Plugin http could not be loaded:
> dlopen(/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1/lib/plugin/http.so,
> 0x0002): tried:
> '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mariadb/10.8.3_1/lib/plugin/http.so' (no such
> file)

I have also tried replacing host with "localhost" and I get this issue:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'data_analyst'@'localhost'
> (using password: YES)

I am not sure how I can connect to get data from the database even though when I connect directly to the webpage I get access to it but when I try the same on command line I am unable to.

Comment: MariaDB doesn't speak http protocol. Try to connect without http://

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are using MariaDB as your DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `mysql -h` it takes a hostname as an argument, not a url. As using `localhost` as the hostname generates `access denied`, its making a connection so `-h` isn't needed as an option (`localhost` is the default`).

There needs to be a space between `-p` and the `database name`. Check the non-root user authentication password.